# onclick function fails to update sql

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this button

```
<button id = "addBtn-1" onclick = "noneAdd();add1()">Add to My Classes</button>
```

It calls a function called `add1()` from my js file, which adds and removes classes and also calls `add()`:

```
function add(){
    $.ajax({url:"add.php",
    success:function(result){
        alert("Added to My Classes");
    }
    });
}
```

which calls my php file, add.php:

```
require_once "config.php";
include "classes.php";

$myun = $_SESSION["un"];
function bookmark1Add(){

    $sql = "SELECT testclass1 FROM classes WHERE username = ?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql)){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_un);
        $param_un = $myun;

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $myclass1);

            if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

                if($myclass1 == 0){

                    $sql2 = "UPDATE classes
                    SET testclass1 = 1";

                    if($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql2)){

                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", "param_un");
                        $param_un = $myun;

                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2)){
                            header("Refresh:0");
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "Something went wrong, please try again later!";
                        }
                    }
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

bookmark1Add();
```

This line of code is supposed to update the data in my table, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I click the button, nothing changes in the database, however the adding and removing of classes from `add1()` works so it succeeded in calling the function

Comment: You really should set a type on your button `<button type="button" ...>`

Comment: Add an error handler to your Ajax call and see if it is called. Look at the network request. Add debugging to your PHP and see if it is called. You really should show all the code involved. Where is add1? where is noneAdd? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: $param_un is not defined, tip, return early rather than nesting so many if statements

Comment: @epascarello there were no errors in console. noneAdd and add1 also had no relation to the problem above, which was why I had left them out. noneAdd simply removes and adds the "none" class, which is set to display:none. add1 calls on add and also changes the class of an element, however changing the class does not have any effect on the sql update. I had left them out of the question deliberately

Comment: @LawrenceCherone could you perhaps specify where $param_un is not defined? to my knowledge, $param_un had been defined twice in the php file

Answer (score 0):

nvm I made the code much simpler since the one above was way too complicated and rat it on its own to see if there were any bugs.

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
include "classes.php";

$myun = $_SESSION["un"];
$sql = "UPDATE classes SET testclass1 = 1 WHERE username = '$myun'";

if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    header: "Refresh:0";
}
?>
```

this worked way better